# What does "ride on" mean in the following context?

Tags: history

I came across this phrase reading [John Adams by David McCullough](https://books.google.fr/books?id=GHMnz8G0GTcC&pg=PA442&lpg=PA442&dq=to%20jefferson%20it%20was%20a%20matter%20of%20necessity,%20given%20his%20hatred%20for&source=bl&ots=9o3DR4RPKi&sig=EQ1y-XPaPOp_C23-oQgN9OTQRIM&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=to%20jefferson%20it%20was%20a%20matter%20of%20necessity%2C%20given%20his%20hatred%20for&f=false)

> As always, he (Jefferson) avoided open dispute, debate, controversy, or any kind of confrontation, but behind the scenes he was unrelenting and extremely effective. To Jefferson it was a matter of necessity, given his hatred of Hamilton and all that was ***riding on*** what he called the "beautiful" revolution in France.

So according to Google, 'ride on' means 'depend/calculate on'. Is it a correct definition in this context?

Comment: "Riding on" is an idiom for qualifying what risk a person is taking by either doing or not doing something, or saying or not saying something. For example, if you place great importance on, say, passing a crucial examination in school, you could say that you have a great deal riding on passing the exam. In other words, a great deal is at risk if you fail the exam. Perhaps by failing, you will not be accepted into the college to which you've applied. The idiom may have come from horseracing. Someone at the race track might ask you, "How much do you have riding on your horse?"

Comment: If you bet a great deal on your horse, you have virtually a truckload of cash riding on that horse--along with the jockey, of course! Put differently, you have a great deal to lose.

Comment: Yeah, the allusion is to horse race gambling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you  ***[ride on someone or something](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ride-on-sth-sb)*** it means that the outcome (usually an important one) you are hoping for  ***depends on*** someone or something:

> When something important, such as your reputation or money, rides on a particular person or thing, it will be won or achieved if that person or thing is successful:
>
> - *The future of the company now rides on the new managing director.
>   I have a lot of money riding on that horse (= I will win or lose a lot of money if that horse wins or loses the race).*

(Cambridge Dictionary)